# Como achar chave privada de endereço bitcoin?

Tags: criptografia, bitcoin

Como faço para obter a chave privada a partir dos dados abaixo?

> **KEY PUBLIC:** 04f2327c57013916e94041ee3ee6f7fcb3dd9cc92c1b7900f51ddfa277eac6b1e175d825d8ce295502cee0f912a18c15cdf2051a16b1d658c64d3b4b3aa4536cf5
>
> **SHA-256:** 673c32048f3643920a724c2be10ff9be1c562e3833be49e41ad7180bdf571a03
>
> **RIPEMD160:** 713afb1cf583fbfc43ef1de90421e0df9f48352d
>
> **+BIT:** 00713afb1cf583fbfc43ef1de90421e0df9f48352d
>
> **HEX-HASH:** 4df94906f14d296f99c032e7ad59d0d2fae3a9f3a83fffee356d484ce4af969d
>
> **HEX-HASH:** 0ed48be1b086dabb9e5fee3848e082ac4a57b1063cfb9c9f21bf5c539f646767
>
> **CHECKSUM:** 0ed48be1
>
> **HASH160:** 00713afb1cf583fbfc43ef1de90421e0df9f48352d0ed48be1
>
> **ADDRESS:** 1BKi1k4GmLphXHrWwVCG4uoz33e3ymRoXW

Gostaria de entender melhor como é feito os cálculos pra se chegar em um resultado entre endereço e chave pública. Achar na força bruta não é a intenção.

Comment: Pode me dizer o que já tentou? Pelo que eu saiba, a chave pública fala quase nada da chave privada. A encriptação é feita com a pública, mas só pode ser decriptada com a privada, em sistemas de chaves assimétricas

Comment: Tem alguns algoritmos específicos que quebram algumas chaves, mas é dependente de máquinas não convencionais ou demandam muito tempo. Interessa?

Comment: Não, achar na força bruta não é a intenção só gostaria de entender melhor como é feito os cálculos pra se chegar em um resultado entre endereço e chave publica

Comment: E quântico? :-)

Answer (score 7):

Você não faz. Um algoritmo de chave assimétrica é desenvolvido especialmente para que a chave privada **não** seja encontrável a partir da chave pública. Se você pudesse adivinhar a chave privada de uma carteira, seria o mesmo que você ter acesso à própria carteira, e você poderia então gastar as *bitcoins* de outrem.

Se essa carteira era sua e você perdeu a chave privada, então sinto lhe informar, mas estas *bitcoins* estão perdidas.